# Load a JSON file, correct the html and load into BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to process a json file through BeautifulSoup but have no idea how to achieve this...

Below is a copy of the json, I'm trying to go through each id in the json and pull out certain bits of data... does anyone suggest a different route?

```
{
    "line_type":"Test",
    "title":"Test Test Test",
    "timestamp":"201310200000",
    "line": [
                                        { 
            "id":10,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r021\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":9,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r023\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":8,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r024\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":7,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r026\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":6,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r027\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":5,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r028\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":4,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r029\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":3,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r031\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":2,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r032\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":1,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r035\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                }                     ]
}
```

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: What data specifically do you need from the JSON?

Comment: @ChrisLaplante This is just example data, I know i could loop through with a regex but I'd rather do it other ways. If i wanted to get all the titles from within the h3 tags how would you go about this?

Comment: The answers below are correct - you need as JSON module to parse the JSON

Comment: @Hyflex Does my answer suffice, or is there something deeper that you're looking for?

Comment: @Hyflex Does the answer I provided do what you want?

Comment: @Hyflex How does my answer _not_ answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my attempt:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Use requests library to get the JSON data
JSONDATA = requests.request("GET", "http://www.websitehere.com/") #Make sure you include the http part
# Load it with JSON 
JSONDATA = JSONDATA.json()

# Cycle through each `line` in the JSON
for line in JSONDATA['line']:
    # Load stripped html in BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['text'])
    # Prints tidy html
    print soup.prettify()
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this does what you're looking for -- for each line, it loads the 'text' attribute into BeautifulSoup, then pulls out all the attributes you might want. You can generalize this into whatever behavior you want -- should be pretty readable.

```
import json
try:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
myjson = r"""{
    "line_type":"Test",
    "title":"Test Test Test",
    "timestamp":"201310200000",
    "line": [
                                        { 
            "id":10,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r021\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":9,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r023\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":8,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r024\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":7,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r026\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":6,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r027\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":5,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r028\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":4,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r029\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":3,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r031\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":2,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r032\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             { 
            "id":1,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r035\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                }                     ]
}"""

data = json.loads(myjson)

for l in data['line']:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(l['text'])
    #print soup.prettify()
    # Get the H1 ID
    print soup.findAll('h1')[0]['id']
    # Get the text
    print soup.findAll('h1')[0].contents[0].strip()
    # Get the <a> href
    print soup.findAll('a')[0]['href']
    # Get the <a> class
    print soup.findAll('a')[0]['class']
    # Get the <a> text
    print soup.findAll('a')[0].contents[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't process json data with `BeautifulSoup`. You can use the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module like so:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data = r"""
{
    "line_type":"Test",
    "title":"Test Test Test",
    "timestamp":"201310200000",
    "line": [
                                        {
            "id":10,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r021\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":9,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r023\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":8,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r024\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":7,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r026\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":6,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r027\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":5,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r028\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":4,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r029\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":3,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r031\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             {
            "id":2,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r032\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a href=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                } ,                                             **{
            "id":1,
            "text": "<h1 id=\"r035\">\n        Titles here    <\/h3>\n\n            <a hre**f=\"\/restofthewebsite\/here\" class=\"but-cl1\">Link<\/a>\n        \n"                }                     ]
}
"""

s = json.loads(json_data)

# Getting the value of the ids
for i in xrange(0, 10):
    pprint(s['line'][i]['text'])
```

Working link [here](http://ideone.com/oRIHE8). You are likely getting a `ValueError` because you forgot to put the `r` in front of the string declaration.

You *could* also use BeautifulSoup on this, so something like, but that will make things quite slow:

```
# Imports
import json
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

json_data = <as described above>
s = json.loads(json_data)
list_of_html_in_json = [s['line'][i]['text'] for i in xrange(10)]
soup = BeautifulSoup(" ".join(list_of_html_in_json))
print soup.find_all("h1", {"id": "r035"})  # Example
```

I am afraid that since this uses an external library (bs4), I cannot show you an online version of the code. But, I assure you that I've tried and tested it.

Comment: The problem with the second script is what happens if i have another h1 tag with a id and want to only get the second if the two h1 tags...

Comment: @Hyflex Well the problem here is that you are trying to parse HTML within json. JSON will not usually be like this.

Comment: It's not actually my json, I'm scraping it from a lan webpage connection so i have no control on it's output.

Comment: @Hyflex There's your problem then/

Comment: What would be your recommendation, the data from the json isn't actively visible in the html source even though it's visible on the actual webpage, how would you recommend getting data from the json? Regex?

Comment: Regex would be simplest, but you _could_ and I don't recommend it. You _could_ indeed run BeautifulSoup on the extracted HTML.

Comment: how do I get it to only print all of: `<h1 id="r028">\n        Titles here    </h3>\n\n            <a href="/restofthewebsite/here" class="but-cl1">Link</a>`

Comment: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` to your last edit :(

Comment: @Hyflex I think you're getting the `ValueError` because you're not putting the `r` in front of the string declaration for json data. `r` is for raw string.

Answer (score 0):

for the lastest beautifulsoup package, it's now

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

This will help you from running into troubles when you try to run the above script by [Christian Ternus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2797476/christian-ternus)

Comment: I had gathered that already and changed it, but yeah good idea @ChristianTernus with the try, except as that covers everyone :P